# VSCode fails to install extensions remote ssh server when using Remote ssh extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh, proxy, vscode-remote

I'm working in a Windows machine behind a corporate firewall and acessing a linux server also behind a corporate firewall. With the excellent Remote-SSH extension, VSCode is failing to install my extensions in the remote linux machine.

How to fix it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is an improved version of the text:

From my understanding, my local machine downloads the extension code and transfers it to the remote machine. However, there are only a few extensions that attempt to download data directly from the internet.

The primary cause of this failure is that my local machine cannot access the internet directly. My local machine runs on Windows and has a local cntlm proxy running. Usually, restarting my local proxy resolves the issue.

Remote SSH works seamlessly, and I can download extensions using this proxy.

My remote machine runs on Linux. In my .bashrc file, I set my http_proxy and https_proxy variables to another proxy. These variables are correctly set in my terminal, but I don't think VSCode recognizes them.

Solution: Go to preferences, open the `Remote` settings tab, and configure:

- `Http: Proxy Support` as override
- `Http: Proxy` as my remote http proxy. When I set an https proxy URL here, it failed.
- `proxyStrictSSL` is set to false

If VSCode Remote Extensions annoy you prompting for your password multiple times. It's better to configure your SSH keys for the remote machine.

Answer (score 2):

If your remote machine do not have internet access, you can try copying the extensions on your local host to the remote host.

```bash
scp -r ~/.vscode/extensions/ remote-host-name:.vscode-server/
```

Answer (score 1):

I copy my .vscode/extensions to my .vscode-server/ directory. It works for me.

```
cp -rf .vscode/extensions ../.vscode-server/
```